# 'python -i' behaviour with R?

Tags: r

I have an R script file `foobar.R'. I want to run the script, and then leave me in the interactive R session when it's done.

Calling

```
$ Rscript foobar.R
```

or

```
$ R -e "$(cat foobar.R)"
```

does not provide the desired behaviour, since the R interpreter immediately quits when the script is done.

Currently, I am using

```
$ R
> source("foobar.R")
```

The problem is that the second command needs to be typed inside the R interpreter - I would like to do it all in a single line form the shell, so that I can set an alias for it, or simply recall a previous command with the up-arrow.

In essence, I am looking for something like Python's

```
$ python -i foobar.py
```

Does such an option exist for R?